# error of using Löb theorem

Tags: logic

Under the assumption of consistency of a logic theory T,

Logically,

> any statement follows from a contradiction sentence.

For example,

"4 is odd number → 3 is even number"

0=1 → 3=4

Similarly,

> (0=1 is provable) → (0=1)

For a logic theory T,

Löb theorem says that if T ⊢ { (P is provable) → P } ,  then T ⊢ P, so,

> T ⊢ 0=1 .

What's the error of this reasoning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what Löb's theorem says, exactly, in this case. Löb's theorem asserts the following about some class of theories T:

> If T proves that (if T proves P then P), then T proves P.

What does this say when P is a contradiction? Well, first let's break down the meaning of each part carefully.

> T proves P

means "T is inconsistent." Next,

> (if T proves P then P)

means "if T is inconsistent, we get a contradiction," so it means "T is consistent." Next,

> If T proves that (if T proves P then P)

means "if T proves that T is consistent." Finally,

> If T proves that (if T proves P then P), then T proves P.

means "if T proves that T is consistent, then T is inconsistent." And this is *precisely* Gödel's second incompleteness theorem!

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. I want to say my question itself once more. I know 0=1 is not provable. But I just want to know exactly which part of reasoning makes error. I edited my post in virtue of you. you mean,  "{ "any statement follows from a contradiction sentence" is correct, but the fact "(0=1 is provable) → (0=1) " cannot ensure that "(0=1 is provable) → (0=1) " is provable?

Comment: @HoCheol: you are getting confused because you keep saying "0=1 is provable" instead of saying the more accurate "T proves 0=1." As I said above, the claim "(if T proves 0=1 then 0=1)" is equivalent to the claim that T is consistent, which is not always true.

Comment: Thank you. the answer is what I want to. (0=1 is provable then 0=1) is not always true.

Comment: what happen if we assume that T is consistent before these reasoning?

Comment: Lob theorem cannot work under the assumption of consistency?

Comment: @HoCheol: you can assume that T is consistent if you want to, but this assumption needs to be distinguished from the assumption that T can prove its own consistency (which as we now know can only happen if T is inconsistent!).

Comment: so if assume the consistency of theory T, we cannot prove (if 0=1 is provable then 0=1).

Comment: @HoCheol: correct. As noted above, this statement is equivalent to the consistency of T.

Comment: I have a question. How can you know < "if T is inconsistent, we get a contradiction," so it means "T is consistent." > by a single sentence. I cannot understand how you can predicate T's consistent by one single instance.

Comment: @HoCheol: the statement "P implies a contradiction" is equivalent to "P is false." This is just basic propositional logic.

Answer (score 1):

Löb's theorem says that *if it is provable that* P's provability implies P, then P is provable.  The statement "(0=1 is provable)→ (0=1)" is provably equivalent to " ¬(0=1 is provable)", so, by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, it cannot be proved (assuming the system is consistent.)

Comment: I know it cannot be proved. However, I just want to know that what is error of the previous reasoning. Since anything follows from a contradiction, hence if (0=1 is provable) then 3=4 and 5=7 and 0=1. so, 0=1's provability implies 0=1

Comment: @HoCheol: that is incorrect. You are misstating what the "if" part of Lob's theorem says in this case.

Comment: you means that "any statement follows from a contradiction sentence" is incorrect?

Comment: @HoCheol: no, of course that statement is correct, but you aren't correctly stating what Löb's theorem gives you when $P$ is a contradiction.

Comment: @HoCheol: the problem is that $0=1$ is a contradiction but "$0=1$ is provable" is not a contradiction; that is just a true statement about some theories.

Comment: Moreover there are even models of ZFC that satisfy "Pvbl(0=1)" where Pvbl is the formalized provability predicate for ZFC. Those models do *not* satisfy 0=1, though.